# How is "Person" in my Ancestry.com tree related to me?

Tags: ancestry.com

When someone on Ancestry makes a 'Comment' on someone or thing in my tree, Ancestry gives me the name of the person and a  link to it (just as it does when I click 'View Person in Tree'.)

When I click on the link it takes me to that person and shows this person's ancestors but **does not show me any descendants ow how that person related to me**.

I need to know how to see the forward part of the tree, not the past, and **where the individual concerned is in my tree**.

How can I find find this info other than by trial and error searching back in my tree?

I also think that some of these people may have been deleted from my tree but are still showing up -- is this possible?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Genealogy & Family History SE. Some screenshots might help with diagnosis. When viewing the tree, have you switched between pedigree and descendant views (icons on upper left)? Maybe the comment applies to someone without descendants. Is there a relationship (to you) listed on that person's profile page?

Comment: There is no relationship shown on some of these people .  But, this issue is still coming up even when I do a Find Person search for a relative I know is in my tree.  EX.  I can do a Find Person for my Great Great Grandfather, who I know all about, but the search produces him and his ancestors buy no way to show his decedents.